# Maven pom has a reference to an external properties file. How to read that in your java program?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using org.codehaus.mojo plugin and it's read-project-properties goal. Like...

```
  <plugins>
    <!-- Reading properties file for login credentials BEGIN -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>

  <file>${basedir}/../datahubui_project_setup/config.properties</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
 <!-- END Reading properties file for login credentials -->

        <plugin>
```

It build well, no errors. Then in my Java method, I am doing

```
private void readCredentialsFromPropertyFile() {
    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);

    // get the property value and print it out
     System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@"+prop.getProperty("userId"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties` (No such file or directory)

I even tried the different path of the file as "${basedir}/../datahubui_project_setup/config.properties", still no use.

Comment: Do you want a properties file in your jar? Then you need to use it as resource.

Comment: Sorry, the requirements have changed. It is now,
How to run my maven cucumber feature, providing command line options(login credentials) to the program ?

Comment: It would be better to write a new question for that.